# JavaScript SDK auto log me in

Tags: facebook, api, authentication

I am trying to see if something is possible.

If I am updating my website to act as a proxy for me and want to know if there is any way to access myself via Open Graph when someone comes to my site without having me needing to literally log myself in?

I was only hoping to leverage the JavaScript SDK; not looking to have a back-end if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could embed an access token in your javascript code but this is pretty unsafe because other users could look at your source code and use this token themselves.  A much safer way would be to do this with server back-end code.